# SQL is ignoring my tempdb changes

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create multiple files for tempdb, but as soon as I restart the service, it defaults to the original.  I have tried via SMSS or even tried to run the below script - same result.  I need to do the Remove file, otherwise I get "logical files exist" errors:

```
--First remove the old TempDB Memory files
ALTER DATABASE tempdb  REMOVE FILE tempdev2
GO

ALTER DATABASE tempdb  REMOVE FILE tempdevaug
GO

--alter the existing ones
ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
      MODIFY FILE ( NAME = templog , FILENAME = 'm:\templog.ldf' )

ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
      MODIFY FILE ( NAME = tempdev , FILENAME = 'm:\tempdev.mdf', SIZE = 204800 KB, 
          MAXSIZE =     204800, FILEGROWTH = 0 KB)

ALTER DATABASE tempdb
    ADD FILE (NAME = tempdev2, FILENAME = 'm:\tempdev2.mdf', SIZE = 204800 KB, 
          MAXSIZE = 204800,     FILEGROWTH = 0 KB);

ALTER DATABASE tempdb
    ADD FILE (NAME = tempdevaug, FILENAME = 'C:\SQLData\tempdevaug.mdf', SIZE = 1024 KB, 
          MAXSIZE     = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB);
```

Comment: Does the account SQL is running under have permission to those directories?

Comment: no, the account that shows if you go to services.msc and look for sql server. http://sqlandme.com/2013/08/20/sql-service-get-sql-server-service-account-using-t-sql/

Comment: @SqlACID NT Service\MSSQLSERVER

Comment: I removed the tag. Question has nothing to do with SQL per se, but seems to be related to the microsoft implementation.

Comment: And does that account have admin or rights to those directories? Easy test: BACKUP DATABASE ANYDATABASE TO DISK='m:\msdb.bak', does that succeed?

Comment: Seriously: I do object to Microsoft hajacking the `SQL` name (which has been around before Billy Boy was even Potty-proof) Name hijacking must be stopped, IMHO.

Comment: @SqlACID It is the default "install" user group.  It has rights to both the M: drive as above and the SQLData folder on C.

Comment: @wildplasser I thought MSSQL was the only SQL implementation using Tempdb.

Comment: They are the only one using backslashes, that's for sure...

Comment: @wildplasser I think Oracle can too..

Comment: I would check the sql logs, see if there's any errors, it definitely should have "starting up database tempdb", I would also try stopping sql, deleting those files if they exist and start sql.

Comment: @SqlACID You largely hit the nail on the head.  A look in the eventlog revealed that the tempdb was trying to start / attach ALL the files sitting in system.masterfiles (valid paths or not).  They didn't show up on sysfiles - only current valid ones it actually got to.  I used "select physical_name, 'ALTER DATABASE tempdb  REMOVE FILE ' + name + char(13) + char(10) + 'GO' from sys.master_files where database_id = 2 order by physical_name" to find and drop all the invalid ones.  Restart - all good.  Post as answer and I will mark as answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the error logs from a start of SQL service, you should see an entry where tempdb is created, any problems during the mount should be logged.